# Setting style attributes (width, etc) through a function argument in javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables, coding-style, nodes

What I'd like to do is create a function that I can call whenever I need to set a style on an object. I want it to look like this:

```
this.setCSS = function(attribute, value) {
  myHTMLNode.style.attribute = value;
}
```

The arguments being passed in right now are strings, so I thought eval() might do it, but I would like to avoid that because it isn't very efficient.

Any ideas at all?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic object property name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamic-object-property-name)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
myHTMLNode.style[attribute] = value;
```

Comment: I guess I just want to know *why* it works. Usually, square brackets are used for arrays. What's happening here that makes this work the way it does?

Comment: This is called "subscript notation", it allows you to access object-members dynamic. There's also a "dot notation" (what you've tried), this can be used with a constant string. The square brackets you mean are used for building arrays with object-literals, what is a completely different thing. See this for more info(scroll down to "objects") http://javascript.crockford.com/survey.html